# Delphi 10.3 does not install AndroidSDK tools correctly for firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I would like some help to correctly install Android SDK into Delphi 10.3. I want to use firemonkey to create an android app. At compile time, Delphi offers to automatically download and install Android SDK, but the automatic installation fails with an error message -> 'Error when executing action of "AndroidSDKTools" catalog. The action ID is 12.' [This is an image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8igqo.png). The image shows more details of the error situation.

Comment: Contact [Embarcadero Support](http://www.embarcadero.com/support) to open a help ticket. They offer free support for installation related issues.

Comment: You can use Tools->Manage Platforms->Additional Options to install the SDK, to work around this bug.

Comment: 3 Years later, with Delphi 10.4 , it's still the same bug. It does not work out-of-the-box on a freshly installed computer. The workaround does not work anymore. It shows that the SDK tools are already installed, but it seems like a SDK update fails.

Answer (score 2):

@nolaspeaker's comment works.

You can use Tools->Manage Platforms->Additional Options to install the SDK, to work around this bug. – nolaspeaker

Comment: You should not post an answer which merely confirms another user's comment.

Comment: this works. with community edition 10.3.3 if you did not install it already